# The usage of dashes as separator on htaccess duplicate with variable which contain dash also

Tags: .htaccess

I am creating a website where I build dynamic page using dash as separator. The pattern

```
RewriteRule ^sale-(.*)-(.*)-(.*)/ index.php?f=category&type=sale&carBrand=$1&carModel=$2&region=$3 [L,QSA]
```

https://example.com/type-carBrand-carModel-location/

Example

https://example.com/sale-land-rover-range-rover-singapore/

The sample does not fit the pattern because the value also contain dash symbol so it read as separator by htaccess. I expect to get value

```
type = sale
carBrand = land-rover
carModel = range-rover
region = singapore
```

I really appreciate any help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Change your separator sign to slash, example https://example.com/sale/land-rover/range-rover/singapore/

```
RewriteRule ^sale/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/$ index.php?f=category&type=sale&carBrand=$1&carModel=$2&region=$3 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: I would like to use dash (-) instead of slash (/) for SEO purpose. Do you have any solution how to figure it out?